# prove or disprove that there is an injective morphism of G-representations iff there is a surjective morphism of G-representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, morphism

> Prove or disprove that given two G-representations V,W over $\mathbb{c},$ there is an injective morphism of G-representations $\theta : W\to V$ iff there is a surjective morphism of G-representations $\theta' : V\to W$.

Below is my (incomplete) attempt at proving the forward direction.

Suppose there exists an injective morphism $\theta : W\to V$ and suppose the two G-representations are $\rho$ and $\phi.$ Then for any $g\in G,\theta \rho_g = \phi_g \theta.$ Because of injectivity, any $w\in W$ is mapped to a unique $v := \theta(w)\in V$, so let $\theta'(v) = w$ if $\theta(w)=v$ for some w and let $\theta'(v) = 1$ otherwise. Then $\theta'$ is clearly surjective and well-defined. We need to show that for any $v\in V, \theta' \phi_g(v) = \rho_g \theta'(v),$ but I don't think this holds. I'm not exactly sure how to define $\theta'$ for values of v not in the image of $\theta.$

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. Consider $G=\Bbb Z$ and let $V$ be the regular $G$-representation over $\Bbb C$. Let $W$ be the trivial $G$ representation on a one-dimensional vector space. There's a surjective homomorphism of representations: $V \to W$ (just map a free generator of $W$ as a $\Bbb C[G]$-module to any non-zero vector in $W$). But if there was any nonzero homomorphism $W \to V$, we would have $V^G\neq 0$, but in fact we have $V^G=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on the notation $V^G$? I'm not sure what it is. Also, could you elaborate on what exactly the surjective homomorphism of representations from V to W is?

Comment: @user1127 $V^G$ are the $G$-invariants, namely $V^G=\{v \in V \mid \forall g \in G: gv=v\}$. The surjective homomorphism woks like this: We have $W=\Bbb C[G]=\bigoplus_{g \in G} \Bbb C$, let's write $v=(v_g)_{g \in G} \in W$. We send this to $\sum_{g \in G}v_g \in \Bbb C$.